# Understanding Pressure MEMS Technical Information (Relative and Absolute Accuracy)

Tags: accuracy, mems

In my research, I use smartphones pressure sensor data, and I need to understand their errors and limitations. I found the technical chart for the sensor:

[image: BOSCH BMP 180 Pressure Sensor]

But I don't really understand the meaning of the absolute accuracy of -4 .. +2 hPa in the chart, and what is the difference between the absolute and relative accuracy here.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The absolute accuracy is based on the difference between the actual pressure and the pressure indicated by the transducer, in this case it might indicate from 4hPa below to 2hPa above the true pressure.  The relative accuracy describes how well the transducer tracks changed in pressure, so if we draw a graph of indicated vs actual pressure over the two ranges indicated (which will ideally be straight lines) the maximum deviation will be 0.12hPa above or below the straight line.  Put another way, if you compensate for the absolute error then this is the range of nonlinearity you can expect over the specified range of the transducer.

Answer (score 0):

Calibration of any sensor requires precise control of gain and offset error as well as temperature correction.  This can and is often much more than the incremental resolution and the relative accuracy.

Absolute accuracy> Relative accuracy> resolution depends on the quality of the design in overcoming many factors that contribute to gain , offset and non-linearity.

The same is true for DMM's with 3 digits that *might* have +/-1 least significant digit (LSD) relative accuracy but maybe +/-2 LSD of offset and 0.1% gain error thus absolute error is the sum of both these. (hypothetical example)